# Is there a way to express combinations with repetition using permutations with repetition?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

It seems somewhat strange to me that combinations without repetitions can be expressed using permutations without repetitions but the commonly taught method for calculating combinations with repetitions is stars and bars, something that is not related to permutations with repetitions.

So then, is there a way to express combinations with repetitions using permutations with repetitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the stars and bars method is taught is because it is the most simple. I mean, sure, we could find the number of permutations with repetition then subtract off all the duplicates due to order not mattering, but that could get complicated and time consuming real quick.

Take for example: $\{A,B,C\}$

There are $10$ ways to choose $3$ of these with repetition allowed, order not mattering.

Or, one could find the number of permutations with repitition and subtract off the extra: there are $5$ extra counts of the grouping $ABC$, $2$ extra of $AAB$, $2$ of $ABB$, $2$ of $AAC$, $2$ of $ACC$, $2$ of $BBC$, and $2$ of $BCC$. Doing the subtraction yields $$27-5-2-2-2-2-2-2 = 10$$

Doesn't this seem like a lot more work than it needs to be?

On another side note: it shouldn't be so strange that combinations without repitition can be expressed as permutations without repetition. Because we aren't repeating anything, we are exactly over counting each combination by the same factor, $n!$. So dividing by this factor will give us the right answer when we don't care about order.

This trick doesn't work for the case of combinations with repitition, as we aren't over counting each grouping by the same factor, as seen in my example.